# Can't update or push data to mongodb array

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, express, mean-stack

am new to MEAN stack and at present am facing some trouble in adding(pushing) & updating elements to nested arrays in mongodb. I have a model as shown below:

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('Check', {
  appt_date: String,
  details: [
                            {
                              appt_time: String,
                              detail: [ {
                                          name : String,  
                                          doctor_name : String
                                        }
                                      ]
                            }
                        ]



});
```

When using the following codes via Mongo Shell, i can create a document as per the model.

```
db.check.insert({"appt_time":"10/10/16"});
db.check.update({"appt_time":"10/10/16"}, {$push: {"details": {"appt_time":"09:30 AM","detail":[]}}},{upsert:true});
db.check.update({"appt_time":"10/10/16","details.appt_time":"09:30 AM"}, {$push: {"details.$.detail": {"name":"roger","doctor":"timmy"}}},{upsert: true});
```

The controller is as follows:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var check = require('../../models/check');


module.exports.addAppointment = function (req, res){
console.log("time = " + req.body.appt_time);
console.log("date = " + req.body.appt_date);
var checker = new check ({ appt_date: req.body.appt_date });                  
checker.save();
check.update({"appt_date":req.body.appt_time}, {$push: {"details": {"appt_time":req.body.appt_time,"detail":[]}}},{upsert:true});
check.update({"appt_date":req.body.appt_date,"details.appt_time":"req.body.appt_time}, {$push: {"details.$.detail": {"name":"roger","doctor":"timmy"}}},{upsert: true});
res.json(res.body);
}
```

The above code only adds a document for a date given as "25/01/2000"

```
"_id": ObjectId('57b49d6b9835c0cc26312e21'),
"appt_date": "25/01/2000",
"details": [],
"__v": 0
```

What i am in need is this - One date entry, multiple time entries along with corresponding details

```
{
"_id": ObjectId('57b4911cf9e57c0421d1efda'),
"appt_date": "10/10/2016",
"details": [
    {
        "appt_time": "09:30 AM",
        "detail": [
            {
                "name": "roger",
                "doctor": "timmy"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "appt_time": "10:30 AM",
        "detail": [
            {
                "name": "david",
                "doctor": "james"
            }
        ]
    }
   ]
}
```

I am not able to perform the push or update or read operations from this array. I can't take my main project further without solving this. If this is not the proper way to implement the model/data, please advise. So please help me to solve this out. If the question is not clear, I can show you the stuff in real time.

Thanks all... :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of inserting a simple document and then doing updates to add further details, have you tried putting together the entire document first and then doing an insert on it? For example, instead of these lines:

```
var checker = new check ({ appt_date: req.body.appt_date });                  
checker.save();
check.update({"appt_date":req.body.appt_time}, {$push: {"details": {"appt_time":req.body.appt_time,"detail":[]}}},{upsert:true});
check.update({"appt_date":req.body.appt_date,"details.appt_time":"req.body.appt_time}, {$push: {"details.$.detail": {"name":"roger","doctor":"timmy"}}},{upsert: true});
```

You could do something like this instead:

```
var draft_check = {
  "appt_date" : req.body.appt_date,
  "details" : [
    {
       "appt_time":req.body.appt_time,
       "detail" : [
         {
           "name" : "roger",
           "doctor":"timmy"
         }
       ]
    }
};
new check (draft_check).save();
```

That approach can make your code cleaner on the client side, and reduces the number of trips to the database you need to make.

Comment: Thanks, that works. But how can I achieve the following:
1) Suppose I add appt_date: 18/08/2016
2) I provided appt_time : 09:30 AM, name: Roger, doctor: David
// This inserts a new document as per the model.
What should I do to add a new entry to the "" details" array, i.e another appt_time + name + doctor ? The above code creates a new document every time when data is provided. 

What I need is a single date entry, multiple time & details entry .. How can I achieve this ??

Comment: @RogerJacob If you know the values to go into a second element in the "details" array when you are creating the new "check" document, you can include it in the initial "check" definition, similar to above.  But if you are asking about making a later update to an existing check document, that is a separate question I think.